# How to connect Mediawiki to a custom user-database?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, mediawiki, single-sign-on

Sorry for the title, I can't find the right words for this.
Let me explain what I want to do:

I have a Site, and a Wiki (latest Mediawiki).
The Wiki is closed, so you need an account to read/write in the wiki.
But when a user logs in into my site, he shall be automatically be logged in into the wiki when he comes there.

My first look into the mysql mediawiki user-table made me clueless: everything is saved as binary data,
but in my user database it's plaintext, except the password of course.

I don't know how to proceed?

Comment: You may want to share your experience in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Requests_for_comment/AuthManager so that such a job is made easier in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You basically want to have two things:

- One single account database on your website which is used from mediawiki, too.
- Automatic login in mediawiki when the user logs on to your website

## Central user database

Mediawiki has several extensions with connect the user management to a different database, for example:

- [AuthDrupal](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AuthDrupal)
- [AuthJoomla](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AuthJoomla)
- [LDAP](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAP_Authentication)
- [ExtAuthDB](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ExtAuthDB)

You should have a look at ExtAuthDB, since it should be configurable enough for you.

## Single Sign On

Single sign on (SSO) is mostly done by sharing a cookie between the web applications. To make this happen, you need to have the wiki in a subdomain of your main page, i.e. `wiki.example.org` when your website is at `example.org`.

On your website, set a cookie for `.example.org` (note the leading dot in the cookie domain), so it's available for `wiki.example.org`, too.

The cookies content's may either be a full-fledged mediawiki cookie (which you need to create on your website), or a cookie with the relevant user information that an own extension to the wiki reads and logs the user in.
I suggest having a look how [Phpbb_Single_Sign-On](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Phpbb_Single_Sign-On) is implemented and do the same for your site.

Answer (score 2):

You can call MediaWiki [API:Login](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aLogin) on your site login routine and [API:Logout](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aLogout) on logout routine, provide the username and password used on your site and wiki are the same.